# GeoLocation history on Googlemap from array of coordinates from database

Tags: javascript, php

while I can place a marker on the Google Map for single set of co-ordinates like

```
<iframe
  width="100%"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=mykey
    &q=<?=$model->latitude_out ?>,<?= $model->longitude_out?>" >
</iframe>
```

I am not able to make out, how I can make a location history like googleMap timeline(history).
I have pulled the coordinates for geo-locations and stored the same in the database.

for example the array of location my db is like this:

```
"location_positions" : [ { "locationTime" : "04-06-2020 02:54", "Latitude" : null, "Longitude" : null }, { "locationTime" : "04-06-2020 02:56", "Latitude" : null, "Longitude" : null }, { "locationTime" : "04-06-2020 02:57", "Latitude" : null, "Longitude" : null }, { "locationTime" : "04-06-2020 02:58", "Latitude" : "21.4626999", "Longitude" : "83.9729724" } ]
```

Now how I can plot this coordinates in a line - example images.

[image]

No I am not getting the result with the polygon as suggested in the answer. The result I am getting is like in the image below, whereas my actual movement is denoted by green line.

[image]

I need the result as in my first picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to create a function which will draw polylines based on your geolocation data.

Instead of loading your map in an iframe, you will load it via a script, with a callback to the function you will provide to draw the polylines.

All of this is well documented in the official Google api:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex

(link updated following feedback)

Comment: I am sorry, but the solution you suggested is not giving the result as expected. I have added the result image in question.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is correct, only the link is wrong. simple poyline gives the expected result, but your link is to polygon.